# MVC razor - add class to shared layout parent div from a child view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm in the (not entirely unusual) situation of having a containing div in my shared layout:

```
<div class="main-content">
    ** views are rendered here in a fixed width container **
</div>
```

Usually this is fixed width but on certain pages I'd like to add the class "fullwidth" to this container which allows it to fill the entire page width. In this specific case it's because the view will host a Javascript application which requires a large workspace.

I could do this with jQuery but I don't want it to happen after the page has rendered, ideally Razor could append this class to the container.

Is there any way for me to affect the content of a shared layout from within a view? renderSection feels quite close to what I need but it would be quite insane to define a section within a class attribute just to append one class name to it, similarly duplicating the shared layout would be overkill...

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kind of hack-ish but I've used it in the past:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<div class="main-content @ViewBag.ContentCssClass">
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

**SomeView.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.ContentCssClass = "full-width";
}
```

Another alternative is to have a `_Layout.cshtml` and `_LayoutFull.cshtml` and add:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_FullLayout.cshtml";
}
```

This can be either directly in the view, or in that controller's `_ViewStart.cshtml` file (but I never like having two HTML pages to maintain for such a simple change).

Comment: Perfect thanks,
Will keep this question open for a short while to see if there's any "best practice" answers but this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

I've used this approach in a similar situation:

In _Layout.cshtml:

```
<body class="@RenderSection("BodyCssClass", false)">
```

In any views which need to override the body's CSS class:

```
@section BodyCssClass {@Html.Raw("full-width")}
```

This seems like overkill for such a simple thing, but it avoids using the ViewBag, which is a good thing in my book.

Answer (score 1):

I normally add the name of the controller as a class, to help me diffirentiate between pages.

```
<div class="@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString().ToLower().Trim()">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Colin's answer I use a helper:

```
<body class="@Html.RouteHint()">
```

With the following extension method

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString RouteHint<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> htmlHelper, string additionalRouteDataName = "key")
        {
            var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
            var areaName = routeData.DataTokens["area"];
            var controllerName = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            var actionName = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
            var additionalValue = routeData.Values[additionalRouteDataName];
            var className = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", areaName, controllerName, actionName, additionalValue)
                .TrimStart()
                .TrimEnd()
                .ToLower();

            return new MvcHtmlString(className);
        }
```